# Is there anyway to get approved for user_groups for an internal use only app?

Tags: facebook

I am really confused on why FB will not approve anything that tries to use the user_groups permissions.  I have a simple web app that pulls data from the groups that the person using the app is in.  Its something that we are only using internally in our office and do not plan on releasing it to the public at all.

I did it using the new API - and there seems to be no way to get it approved.  Is there anyway to allow specific people to use my app - even though its not approved?  Or am i forced to re-write it using the old API calls w/ out a review?  (obvious downside is it will only run until April 2015).
I do have an old app id I can use to get around the app before a certain date have to use the new api feature.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add all the people in your office that should use this app as 'Testers', using the App Dashboard. That way you can keep your app in Development Mode, so you don't need review.

If you have a lot of people in your office, this might get complicated. But, the user_groups permission is only for apps building a Facebook Experience on a platform for which Facebook is not yet available. So, really hard to get.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That's kind of what I figured. There are about 200 people that would be using it. Adding them as testers is a bit of a hassle, but if that's the only way, then so be it.
I assume doing that would not violate any FB tos or anything like that? Is there a limit on the number of test users?
Also just curious... What platform is available where there is not a FB app? 

Tnx

Comment: If you want to automate the user/roles for your app, you can also consider using the API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/app/roles

Comment: Yea - that will help out a lot.  For somereason - I though that was just for the test users in the developer area, not actually adding users as test users.  Very cool...thanks!